# Replace characters in a string in-place

Tags: c, string, performance, memory-management, replace

I have a function to replace characters in a string, and it works perfectly!
The only problem, however, is that it requires another string to act as buffer to which the modified text will be placed.

This is a disaster to me, because most of my work is about I/O handling. So if I allocate 1024 bytes as a maximum using `calloc` to contain a line, I'll have to duplicate it to have a modified version with the same size (yes, 1024 bytes wasted on string replacement).

Here is the function:

```
void replaceStr(buffer, haystack, needles, n_needles, rep)
    char *buffer;
    const char *haystack, **needles, *rep;
    const size_t n_needles;
{
    if (!buffer || !haystack || !needles || !rep)
        return;
    size_t rep_length = strlen(rep);
    char *found;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_needles; ++i) {
        const char *needle = needles[i];
        const size_t needle_length = strlen(needle);
        while ((found = strstr(haystack, needle))) {
            /* measure the length of what is before needle */
            size_t diff = found - haystack;
            /* copy that part until needle */
            strncpy(buffer, haystack, diff);
            /* copy needle (found == buffer + diff) */
            strcpy(buffer + diff, rep);
            /* adjust pointers */
            buffer += diff + rep_length;
            haystack = found + needle_length;
        }
        /* copy remaining string */
        strcpy(buffer, haystack);
    }
}
```

Having the same string as buffer would result in:
 - Faster code (calls to `calloc` would be unneeded)
 - Memory-efficient code (again, calls to `calloc` would be unneeded)
 - Neater code. Because one line of code is much neater than three (one for allocation, one for function invokation, one for freeing)

My question as you might have guessed is: How can I use the same string as buffer ?

Comment: Is it really a “disaster”?  You can us the same buffer over and over again.  I don't think that this will very likely be a major bottleneck of your program.

Comment: You can only safely replace a string in-place if you know the replacement is shorter than or equal to the original string length, *or* you need to store a 'maximum storage length' somewhere for all strings (and reserve lots of extra space per string).

Comment: @5gon12eder: Well, I admit I exaggerated a bit ;) I already have a global buffer variable and its doing fine for now. Extra 1024 bytes, not a problem. But what if I'm reading from a large input stream ? Then, a global variable just wouldn't be enough ..

Comment: Also, if I was replacing occasionally, a global variable would be unnecessary ..

Comment: The first optimisation would be to replace the nested loops by a single loop, and compile the needles into a DFA ("dictionary search") The buffer problem remains, unless you are sure that the replacement is never larger then its "needle". Also: the strncpy() and strcpy() inside the inner loop could be trivially replaced by memcpy().

Comment: @wildplasser: If it is larger, the function shall still work ..

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can guarantee that the replacement string, `rep`, is always exactly the same size of the search string, `needle`, then you'll likely make your situation much worse and far more complicated to seek an in-place replacement of the original string, since algorithmically you'll have to shuffle the contents of the entire string around.

You'll then replace constant-time O(1) appends to an output buffer with O(N) linear complexity swapping of bytes in the original buffer.

In-place replacement algorithms work well when you are simply overwriting fixed-sized elements in a range, or if you have an algorithm that involves a write pointer that trails behind the read pointer yielding a final result that is less than or equal to the size of the original. In your case, you're dealing with variable-sized replacements and reading and writing at the same overlapping position which could result in a larger result, and that's when you really want a separate place in memory to output results for efficiency because otherwise you'll be dealing with a large amount of overhead shuffling around the same memory to try to reuse it.

Your function signature is fine as is by accepting a pointer to an output buffer. Naturally if the calling code `callocs` and `frees` the buffer every time prior to calling it, that's obviously going to lead to bottleneck-prone code. The calling code should be reusing the same buffer for each thread and passing it down the call stack to avoid recreating it.

Now if you want to optimize the calling code to avoid excessive `callocs` and `frees`, then this could be tricky if you cannot effectively determine an upper bound for the size of the output buffer in advance. In such a case, reuse the same buffer but also keep track of its size and `realloc` when you run into a new input case where it needs to be larger (or simply use `realloc` every time). Then keep on reusing it and rinse and repeat and `free` when done.